# View with horizontal and vertical pan/drag and pinch-zoom

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to have a view who supports horizontal and vertical pan/drag. On top of that, I want to be able to pinch to zoom and double tap to zoom.
Does this view exists on Android or does somebody knows a project who does?

To make it even more difficult, an other view (Button, TextView, VideoView, ...) needs to be added to the view. When the first/parent view is zoomed in or moved around, the subview (Button) needs to move around with the parent.

I've tried multiple solutions, but none of them have al the options I'm looking for.

- https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/tree/master/src/com/example/touch
- http://vivin.net/2011/12/04/implementing-pinch-zoom-and-pandrag-in-an-android-view-on-the-canvas/

Comment: Hi, did you get the final solution for this question? Could you please share it ?

Comment: It would be nice if you could share your solution...

Answer (score 27):

I think it's possible to achieve what you want, but there is, as far as I know build in  solution for it. From the second part of your question I guess that you don't want a zoomable `View` but a `ViewGroup` which is the super class of all Views that can contain other view (e.g. Layouts). Here is some code you could start from building your own ViewGroup most of it comes from [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) blog post:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.*;

public class ZoomableViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = 1;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private float mScaleFactor = 1;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private Matrix mScaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix mScaleMatrixInverse = new Matrix();

    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;
    private Matrix mTranslateMatrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix mTranslateMatrixInverse = new Matrix();

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;

    private float mFocusY;

    private float mFocusX;

    private float[] mInvalidateWorkingArray = new float[6];
    private float[] mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];
    private float[] mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];


    public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        mTranslateMatrix.setTranslate(0, 0);
        mScaleMatrix.setScale(1, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                child.layout(l, t, l+child.getMeasuredWidth(), t + child.getMeasuredHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mFocusX, mFocusY);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = ev.getX();
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = ev.getY();
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = screenPointsToScaledPoints(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray);
        ev.setLocation(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0],
                mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    /**
     * Although the docs say that you shouldn't override this, I decided to do
     * so because it offers me an easy way to change the invalidated area to my
     * likening.
     */
    @Override
    public ViewParent invalidateChildInParent(int[] location, Rect dirty) {

        mInvalidateWorkingArray[0] = dirty.left;
        mInvalidateWorkingArray[1] = dirty.top;
        mInvalidateWorkingArray[2] = dirty.right;
        mInvalidateWorkingArray[3] = dirty.bottom;


        mInvalidateWorkingArray = scaledPointsToScreenPoints(mInvalidateWorkingArray);
        dirty.set(Math.round(mInvalidateWorkingArray[0]), Math.round(mInvalidateWorkingArray[1]),
                Math.round(mInvalidateWorkingArray[2]), Math.round(mInvalidateWorkingArray[3]));

        location[0] *= mScaleFactor;
        location[1] *= mScaleFactor;
        return super.invalidateChildInParent(location, dirty);
    }

    private float[] scaledPointsToScreenPoints(float[] a) {
        mScaleMatrix.mapPoints(a);
        mTranslateMatrix.mapPoints(a);
        return a;
    }

    private float[] screenPointsToScaledPoints(float[] a){
        mTranslateMatrixInverse.mapPoints(a);
        mScaleMatrixInverse.mapPoints(a);
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = ev.getX();
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = ev.getY();

        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = scaledPointsToScreenPoints(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray);

        ev.setLocation(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0], mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                // Save the ID of this pointer
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
                final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;
                mTranslateMatrix.preTranslate(dx, dy);
                mTranslateMatrix.invert(mTranslateMatrixInverse);

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                invalidate();
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
                final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            if (detector.isInProgress()) {
                mFocusX = detector.getFocusX();
                mFocusY = detector.getFocusY();
            }
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));
            mScaleMatrix.setScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                    mFocusX, mFocusY);
            mScaleMatrix.invert(mScaleMatrixInverse);
            invalidate();
            requestLayout();


            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

What this class should be able to do, is dragging the content around and allowing pinch to zoom, double tap to zoom isn't possible right now, but it should be easy to implement in the `onTouchEvent` method.

If you have questions how to layout the childs in your ViewGroup I found this [video](http://www.parleys.com/#st=5&id=2191&sl=38) very helpfull or if you have any further questions how single methods work or anything else feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: There are a few errors in this including that you need to extend ViewGroup and you have missed out a few '}'.

Comment: @Artjom i wondering, why not use setScaleX/Y on the viewgroup instead of having to tranfrom the clip, touch points etc yourself?

Comment: Is it possible to stop zooming out when the View reaches the 1:1 scale? Is it simple to achieve?

Comment: Had to make some modifications to get this to work, but it does do the job. Ended up using a single matrix and just the onTouchEvent method based on [this](http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/).

Comment: How can I limit the ZoomableViewGroup when translating ?

Comment: Thank you for this Implementation!!!! It really helped me not to redraw everything...

Comment: How to implement rotation with this example? Need some tips.

Comment: I'm hoping to use this in one activity and pass back its configuration to a parent activity (in the parent the zoomableviewgroup should appear as it was set in the child). How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 17):

Repost of @Artjom answer with minor errors fixed, namely braces, imports, and extending ViewGroup.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.*;

public class ZoomableViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = 1;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private float mScaleFactor = 1;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private Matrix mScaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix mScaleMatrixInverse = new Matrix();

    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;
    private Matrix mTranslateMatrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix mTranslateMatrixInverse = new Matrix();

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;

    private float mFocusY;

    private float mFocusX;

    private float[] mInvalidateWorkingArray = new float[6];
    private float[] mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];
    private float[] mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];


    public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        mTranslateMatrix.setTranslate(0, 0);
        mScaleMatrix.setScale(1, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                child.layout(l, t, l+child.getMeasuredWidth(), t + child.getMeasuredHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mFocusX, mFocusY);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = ev.getX();
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = ev.getY();
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = screenPointsToScaledPoints(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray);
        ev.setLocation(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0],
                mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    /**
     * Although the docs say that you shouldn't override this, I decided to do
     * so because it offers me an easy way to change the invalidated area to my
     * likening.
     */
    @Override
    public ViewParent invalidateChildInParent(int[] location, Rect dirty) {

        mInvalidateWorkingArray[0] = dirty.left;
        mInvalidateWorkingArray[1] = dirty.top;
        mInvalidateWorkingArray[2] = dirty.right;
        mInvalidateWorkingArray[3] = dirty.bottom;


        mInvalidateWorkingArray = scaledPointsToScreenPoints(mInvalidateWorkingArray);
        dirty.set(Math.round(mInvalidateWorkingArray[0]), Math.round(mInvalidateWorkingArray[1]),
                Math.round(mInvalidateWorkingArray[2]), Math.round(mInvalidateWorkingArray[3]));

        location[0] *= mScaleFactor;
        location[1] *= mScaleFactor;
        return super.invalidateChildInParent(location, dirty);
    }

    private float[] scaledPointsToScreenPoints(float[] a) {
        mScaleMatrix.mapPoints(a);
        mTranslateMatrix.mapPoints(a);
        return a;
    }

    private float[] screenPointsToScaledPoints(float[] a){
        mTranslateMatrixInverse.mapPoints(a);
        mScaleMatrixInverse.mapPoints(a);
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = ev.getX();
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = ev.getY();

        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = scaledPointsToScreenPoints(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray);

        ev.setLocation(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0], mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                // Save the ID of this pointer
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
                final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;
                mTranslateMatrix.preTranslate(dx, dy);
                mTranslateMatrix.invert(mTranslateMatrixInverse);

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                invalidate();
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
                final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            if (detector.isInProgress()) {
                mFocusX = detector.getFocusX();
                mFocusY = detector.getFocusY();
            }
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));
            mScaleMatrix.setScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                    mFocusX, mFocusY);
            mScaleMatrix.invert(mScaleMatrixInverse);
            invalidate();
            requestLayout();


            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I add a child view in ZoomableViewGroup, after zoom, the touched coordinates of the child be get wrong. How can I fix it ?

Comment: for who facing the problem like me: change the order of the method <br/>`private float[] screenPointsToScaledPoints(float[] a)` to: <br/>

`private float[] screenPointsToScaledPoints(float[] a) {
        mScaleMatrixInverse.mapPoints(a);
        mTranslateMatrixInverse.mapPoints(a);
        return a;
    }`

Answer (score 14):

Based on the given answers I used this code to get the pan and zoom functions to work. Had problems with the pivot-points at first.

```
public class ZoomableViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    // these matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix matrixInverse = new Matrix();
    private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    // we can be in one of these 3 states
    private static final int NONE = 0;
    private static final int DRAG = 1;
    private static final int ZOOM = 2;
    private int mode = NONE;
    // remember some things for zooming
    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private PointF mid = new PointF();
    private float oldDist = 1f;
    private float[] lastEvent = null;

    private boolean initZoomApplied=false;

    private float[] mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];
    private float[] mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = ev.getX();
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = ev.getY();
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = screenPointsToScaledPoints(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray);
        ev.setLocation(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0],
                mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private float[] scaledPointsToScreenPoints(float[] a) {
        matrix.mapPoints(a);
        return a;
    }

    private float[] screenPointsToScaledPoints(float[] a){
        matrixInverse.mapPoints(a);
        return a;
    }

    public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);      
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    /**
     * Determine the space between the first two fingers
     */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
     */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }


    private void init(Context context){

    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                child.layout(l, t, l+child.getMeasuredWidth(), t + child.getMeasuredHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        float[] values = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(values);
        float container_width = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]*widthSize;
        float container_height = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]*heightSize;

        //Log.d("zoomToFit", "m width: "+container_width+" m height: "+container_height);
        //Log.d("zoomToFit", "m x: "+pan_x+" m y: "+pan_y);

        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

                if(i==0 && !initZoomApplied && child.getWidth()>0){
                    int c_w = child.getWidth();
                    int c_h = child.getHeight();

                    //zoomToFit(c_w, c_h, container_width, container_height);
                }
            }
        }        

    }

    private void zoomToFit(int c_w, int c_h, float container_width, float container_height){
        float proportion_firstChild = (float)c_w/(float)c_h;
        float proportion_container = container_width/container_height;

        //Log.d("zoomToFit", "firstChildW: "+c_w+" firstChildH: "+c_h);
        //Log.d("zoomToFit", "proportion-container: "+proportion_container);
        //Log.d("zoomToFit", "proportion_firstChild: "+proportion_firstChild);

        if(proportion_container<proportion_firstChild){
            float initZoom = container_height/c_h;
            //Log.d("zoomToFit", "adjust height with initZoom: "+initZoom);
            matrix.postScale(initZoom, initZoom);
            matrix.postTranslate(-1*(c_w*initZoom-container_width)/2, 0);
            matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
        }else {
            float initZoom = container_width/c_w;
            //Log.d("zoomToFit", "adjust width with initZoom: "+initZoom);
            matrix.postScale(initZoom, initZoom);
            matrix.postTranslate(0, -1*(c_h*initZoom-container_height)/2);
            matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
        }
        initZoomApplied=true;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // handle touch events here
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = event.getX();
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = event.getY();

        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = scaledPointsToScreenPoints(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray);

        event.setLocation(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0], mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mode = DRAG;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                //d = rotation(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                    matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                        matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Credits to the onTouch function go to: http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/
Thanks to Artjom for his approach to dipatch the touch events.

I added a zoomToFit method which is commented at this point because most people wont't need this. It fits the children to the size of the container and takes the first child as reference for the scalefactor.

Comment: how to limit the scale factor ? I want the zoom to be within 0.75 and 4, for example.

Comment: You can define a MAX_ZOOM: `int MAX_ZOOM = 4;` and then add this line before you post the scale (matrix.postScale): `float[] values = new float[9];
                    matrix.getValues(values); if(scale*values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] >= MAX_ZOOM){
                      scale = MAX_ZOOM/values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                        }`

Comment: Good code! The zoom is better (starts immediately, which is not the case in Alex's code) and with no pivot-points problem. However, it doesn't allow to zoom with a double-tap-drag action.

Comment: On my phone (Nexus 4, CyanogenMod13, Android 6.0.1), the subview starts below status bar whereas `ZoomableViewGroup` starts just below the status bar. If in `dispatchDraw ` I replace `canvas.setMatrix(matrix);` with: `float[] values = new float[9]; matrix.getValues(values); canvas.translate(values[Matrix.MTRANS_X], values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]); canvas.scale(values[Matrix.MSCALE_X], values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);`, it works well...

Comment: Margins are seemingly ignored by default. To support them, change the line in `onLayout` to `child.layout(child.getLeft(), child.getTop(), child.getLeft() + child.getMeasuredWidth(), child.getTop()  + child.getMeasuredHeight());`. Additionally, add `super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)` to the start of the method.

Comment: To change the minimum + maximum zoom factors, you should actually change the line `mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 2.0f));` to your minimum + maximum floats.

Answer (score 14):

[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479859/view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-pan-drag-and-pinch-zoom/12497670#answer-33371584) answer is almost the best (I have one position bug on my phone): the zoom starts immediately (which is not the case with [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479859/view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-pan-drag-and-pinch-zoom/12497670#answer-33371584#answer-19204645)'s code), and the zoom is made at the right pivot-point.

However, contrary to [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479859/view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-pan-drag-and-pinch-zoom/12497670#answer-33371584#answer-19204645)'s code, it is not possible to zoom with a "double-tap-drag" gesture (not a well known gesture but a very useful one to zoom with only one finger, like in Google Chrome or Google Maps apps). So here is a modification of [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479859/view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-pan-drag-and-pinch-zoom/12497670#answer-33371584)'s code to make it possible (and fixing the subview position bug):

```
public class ZoomableView extends ViewGroup {

    // States.
    private static final byte NONE = 0;
    private static final byte DRAG = 1;
    private static final byte ZOOM = 2;

    private byte mode = NONE;

    // Matrices used to move and zoom image.
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix matrixInverse = new Matrix();
    private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // Parameters for zooming.
    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private PointF mid = new PointF();
    private float oldDist = 1f;
    private float[] lastEvent = null;
    private long lastDownTime = 0l;

    private float[] mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];
    private float[] mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = ev.getX();
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = ev.getY();
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = screenPointsToScaledPoints(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray);
        ev.setLocation(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0], mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public ZoomableView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }


    private void init(Context context) {

    }


    /**
     * Determine the space between the first two fingers
     */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
     */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    private float[] scaledPointsToScreenPoints(float[] a) {
        matrix.mapPoints(a);
        return a;
    }

    private float[] screenPointsToScaledPoints(float[] a) {
        matrixInverse.mapPoints(a);
        return a;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                child.layout(left, top, left + child.getMeasuredWidth(), top + child.getMeasuredHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float[] values = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(values);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(values[Matrix.MTRANS_X], values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]);
        canvas.scale(values[Matrix.MSCALE_X], values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // handle touch events here
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = event.getX();
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = event.getY();

        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = scaledPointsToScreenPoints(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray);

        event.setLocation(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0], mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                mode = DRAG;
                lastEvent = null;
                long downTime = event.getDownTime();
                if (downTime - lastDownTime < 300l) {
                    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                    if (Math.max(Math.abs(start.x - event.getX()), Math.abs(start.y - event.getY())) < 40.f * density) {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        mid.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = ZOOM;
                        lastEvent = new float[4];
                        lastEvent[0] = lastEvent[1] = event.getX();
                        lastEvent[2] = lastEvent[3] = event.getY();
                    }
                    lastDownTime = 0l;
                } else {
                    lastDownTime = downTime;
                }
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                    matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                    if (Math.max(Math.abs(start.x - event.getX()), Math.abs(start.y - event.getY())) > 20.f * density) {
                        lastDownTime = 0l;
                    }
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                        float newDist = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist > 10f * density) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                            matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                        }
                    } else {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = event.getY() / start.y;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                        matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: How to get transformed x,y coordinates on `onTouchEvent` ?

Comment: I had an issue with Thomas's answer. My view's hit boxes was below then where actual view is (for android < 25 API). I figured out that problem was with dispatchDraw method. Since i don't know anything about matrixes i was highly frustraded. You dispatchDraw fixed the problem. I realy want to understand how does that magic works. I want to learn about matrix and, maybe, ViewPort techniques with Rect objects. Can you advice good sources to learn for that?
I realy don't like to do something, when i can't figure out how does it work.
Thank you for the code, and thank you @Thomas aswell.

Comment: This is the best solution.

Comment: I have an issue with this solution. Originally this solution is perfect, but only if this viewgroup not contains clickable views inside, because the click of the subview receives the onTouchEvent(). Can you see if you can add support for dragging with clickable views inside? I think using onInterceptTouchEvent() it could be possible, but i'm not expert managing the touch events. Thanks

Comment: Amazing Answer buddy! , no one mention how to use it ,                                                   <app.kdblue.com.movablefloatingbutton.ZoomableView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">                                                            put_your_views_here  
 </app.kdblue.com.movablefloatingbutton.ZoomableView>

Comment: @Donkey , Thanks for code ! can you say, how to set minimum zoom and maximum zoom .

Comment: @Donkey ! Thank you very much!! I was using Thomas answer with a little editions but was having a lot of problems with lower level APIs. Your answer saved me :)

Answer (score 1):

This custom view is a subclass of the Android standard imageView and adds to it (multi)touch pan and zoom (and double tap zoom, as well):

https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom

http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

It is similar to the MikeOrtiz's TouchImageView that you already know but adds some more features.

You can use it inside a view "stack" (an Android FrameLayout or something like that) together with the other textView(s) you need. (I mean a "pile" of views, like a pile of dishes or a stack of cards. In other words, a pile of views stacked one over the next on the Z axis.)

Moving all your views together requires that you take control of the Android Gestures (multitouch) mechanism and write the required code. There isn't any ready-to-use solution for your (quite complex) requirement. Have a look at this article:

http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Answer (score 1):

I am using some modified versions of the codes posted here. This ZoomLayout uses Android gesture recognizers for scroll and scale. It also preserves the pivot and boundaries when zooming or panning.

https://github.com/maxtower/ZoomLayout/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/maxtower/testzoomlayout/ZoomLayout.java

To preserve pan boundaries:

```
if (contentSize != null)
    {
        float[] values = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(values);
        float totX = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X] + distanceX;
        float totY = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] + distanceY;
        float sx = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];

        Rect viewableRect = new Rect();
        ZoomLayout.this.getDrawingRect(viewableRect);
        float offscreenWidth = contentSize.width() - (viewableRect.right - viewableRect.left);
        float offscreenHeight = contentSize.height() - (viewableRect.bottom - viewableRect.top);
        float maxDx = (contentSize.width() - (contentSize.width() / sx)) * sx;
        float maxDy = (contentSize.height() - (contentSize.height() / sx)) * sx;
        if (totX > 0 && distanceX > 0)
        {
            distanceX = 0;
        }
        if (totY > 0 && distanceY > 0)
        {
            distanceY = 0;
        }

        if(totX*-1 > offscreenWidth+maxDx && distanceX < 0)
        {
            distanceX = 0;
        }
        if(totY*-1 > offscreenHeight+maxDy && distanceY < 0)
        {
            distanceY = 0;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I came with this solution (A mix of your codes and some of my ideas) :

- double tap zoom and unzoom
- zoom and unzoom afterdouble tap (with one finger)
- pan around ok
- pinch zoom ok and it zooms where you point
- child views are touchable
- layout with border ! (Cant get off the layout by unzooming or by panning around)

its not animated but fullyworking. enjoy

Usage :

```
<com.yourapppath.ZoomableViewGroup
    android:id="@+id/zoomControl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayoutZoom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/planImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/yourdrawable"
            android:scaleType="center" />

    </FrameLayout>
</com.yourapppath.ZoomableViewGroup>
```

and here is the zoomableViewGroup Java file, just copy and use :

```
public class ZoomableViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    private boolean doubleTap = false;


    private float MIN_ZOOM = 1f;
    private float MAX_ZOOM = 2.5f;
    private float[] topLeftCorner = {0, 0};
    private float scaleFactor;

    // States.
    private static final byte NONE = 0;
    private static final byte DRAG = 1;
    private static final byte ZOOM = 2;

    private byte mode = NONE;

    // Matrices used to move and zoom image.
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix matrixInverse = new Matrix();
    private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // Parameters for zooming.
    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private PointF mid = new PointF();
    private float oldDist = 1f;
    private float[] lastEvent = null;
    private long lastDownTime = 0l;
    private long downTime = 0l;

    private float[] mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];
    private float[] mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = ev.getX();
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = ev.getY();
        mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = screenPointsToScaledPoints(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray);
        ev.setLocation(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0], mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    /**
     * Determine the space between the first two fingers
     */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
     */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    private float[] scaledPointsToScreenPoints(float[] a) {
        matrix.mapPoints(a);
        return a;
    }

    private float[] screenPointsToScaledPoints(float[] a) {
        matrixInverse.mapPoints(a);
        return a;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                child.layout(left, top, left + child.getMeasuredWidth(), top + child.getMeasuredHeight());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
       super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float[] values = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(values);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(values[Matrix.MTRANS_X], values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]);
        canvas.scale(values[Matrix.MSCALE_X], values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);
        topLeftCorner[0] = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        topLeftCorner[1] = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
        scaleFactor = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // handle touch events here
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = event.getX();
        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = event.getY();

        mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = scaledPointsToScreenPoints(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray);

        event.setLocation(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0], mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                mode = DRAG;
                lastEvent = null;
                downTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                if (downTime - lastDownTime < 250l) {
                    doubleTap = true;
                    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                    if (Math.max(Math.abs(start.x - event.getX()), Math.abs(start.y - event.getY())) < 40.f * density) {
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);                                                         //repetition of savedMatrix.setmatrix
                        mid.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = ZOOM;
                        lastEvent = new float[4];
                        lastEvent[0] = lastEvent[1] = event.getX();
                        lastEvent[2] = lastEvent[3] = event.getY();
                    }    
                    lastDownTime = 0l;
                } else {
                    doubleTap = false;
                    lastDownTime = downTime;
                }
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


                if (doubleTap && scaleFactor < 1.8f){
                    matrix.postScale(2.5f/scaleFactor, 2.5f/scaleFactor, mid.x, mid.y);
                } else if(doubleTap && scaleFactor >= 1.8f){
                    matrix.postScale(1.0f/scaleFactor, 1.0f/scaleFactor, mid.x, mid.y);
                }

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(topLeftCorner[0] >= 0){
                            matrix.postTranslate(-topLeftCorner[0],0);
                        } else if (topLeftCorner[0] < -getWidth()*(scaleFactor-1)){
                            matrix.postTranslate((-topLeftCorner[0]) - getWidth()*(scaleFactor-1) ,0);
                        }
                        if(topLeftCorner[1] >= 0){
                            matrix.postTranslate(0,-topLeftCorner[1]);
                        } else if (topLeftCorner[1] < -getHeight()*(scaleFactor-1)){
                            matrix.postTranslate(0,(-topLeftCorner[1]) - getHeight()*(scaleFactor-1));
                        }
                        matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                        invalidate();
                    }
                }, 1);

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                    matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                    if (Math.max(Math.abs(start.x - event.getX()), Math.abs(start.y - event.getY())) > 20.f * density) {
                        lastDownTime = 0l;
                    }
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                        float newDist = spacing(event);
                        if (newDist > 10f * density) {
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                            float[] values = new float[9];
                            matrix.getValues(values);
                            if (scale * values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] >= MAX_ZOOM) {
                                scale = MAX_ZOOM / values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                            }
                            if (scale * values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] <= MIN_ZOOM) {
                                scale = MIN_ZOOM / values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                            }
                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                            matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ( SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - downTime > 250l) {
                            doubleTap = false;
                        }
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = event.getY() / start.y;
                        float[] values = new float[9];
                        matrix.getValues(values);
                        if (scale * values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] >= MAX_ZOOM) {
                            scale = MAX_ZOOM / values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                        }
                        if (scale * values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] <= MIN_ZOOM) {
                            scale = MIN_ZOOM / values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                        }
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                        matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }


        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: if we add a fragment into this viewgroup, it is not working as expected. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To get better permormance of Zooming in Alex's code add following changes

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        if (detector.isInProgress()) {
            mFocusX = detector.getFocusX();
            mFocusY = detector.getFocusY();
        }

        mFocusX = (mFocusX + mLastTouchX)/2;  // get center of touch
        mFocusY = (mFocusY + mLastTouchY)/2;  // get center of touch

        mScaleFactor = Math.max(1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 2.0f));
        mScaleMatrix.setScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,mFocusX, mFocusY);
        mScaleMatrix.invert(mScaleMatrixInverse);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in a zooming/panning LinearLayout, I modified the version posted by Alex to lay things out vertically and cap the panning to the visible views. I use this for bitmaps from the PDFRenderer. I've tested this but if you notice any bugs please post because I'd like to know about them, too!

Note: I opted not to implement double tapping, since QuickScale works.

```
public class ZoomableLinearLayout extends ViewGroup {

   private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = 1;
   private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

   private float mScaleFactor = 1;
   private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
   private Matrix mScaleMatrix = new Matrix();
   private Matrix mScaleMatrixInverse = new Matrix();

   private float mPosX;
   private float mPosY;
   private Matrix mTranslateMatrix = new Matrix();
   private Matrix mTranslateMatrixInverse = new Matrix();

   private float mLastTouchX;
   private float mLastTouchY;

   private float mFocusY;
   private float mFocusX;

   private int mCanvasWidth;
   private int mCanvasHeight;

   private float[] mInvalidateWorkingArray = new float[6];
   private float[] mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];
   private float[] mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];

   private boolean mIsScaling;

   public ZoomableLinearLayout(Context context) {
      super(context);
      mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
      mTranslateMatrix.setTranslate(0, 0);
      mScaleMatrix.setScale(1, 1);
   }

   public ZoomableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
      super(context, attributeSet);
      mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
      mTranslateMatrix.setTranslate(0, 0);
      mScaleMatrix.setScale(1, 1);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
      int childCount = getChildCount();
      for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
         View child = getChildAt(i);
         if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
            child.layout(l, t, l+child.getMeasuredWidth(), t += child.getMeasuredHeight());
         }
      }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

      int height = 0;
      int width = 0;
      int childCount = getChildCount();
      for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
         View child = getChildAt(i);
         if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
            measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            height += child.getMeasuredHeight();
            width = Math.max(width, child.getMeasuredWidth());
         }
      }
      mCanvasWidth = width;
      mCanvasHeight = height;
   }

   @Override
   protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.save();
      canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
      canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mFocusX, mFocusY);
      super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
      canvas.restore();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = ev.getX();
      mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = ev.getY();
      mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = screenPointsToScaledPoints(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray);
      ev.setLocation(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0],
            mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);
      return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
   }

   /**
    * Although the docs say that you shouldn't override this, I decided to do
    * so because it offers me an easy way to change the invalidated area to my
    * likening.
    */
   @Override
   public ViewParent invalidateChildInParent(int[] location, Rect dirty) {

      mInvalidateWorkingArray[0] = dirty.left;
      mInvalidateWorkingArray[1] = dirty.top;
      mInvalidateWorkingArray[2] = dirty.right;
      mInvalidateWorkingArray[3] = dirty.bottom;

      mInvalidateWorkingArray = scaledPointsToScreenPoints(mInvalidateWorkingArray);
      dirty.set(Math.round(mInvalidateWorkingArray[0]), Math.round(mInvalidateWorkingArray[1]),
            Math.round(mInvalidateWorkingArray[2]), Math.round(mInvalidateWorkingArray[3]));

      location[0] *= mScaleFactor;
      location[1] *= mScaleFactor;
      return super.invalidateChildInParent(location, dirty);
   }

   private float[] scaledPointsToScreenPoints(float[] a) {
      mScaleMatrix.mapPoints(a);
      mTranslateMatrix.mapPoints(a);
      return a;
   }

   private float[] screenPointsToScaledPoints(float[] a){
      mTranslateMatrixInverse.mapPoints(a);
      mScaleMatrixInverse.mapPoints(a);
      return a;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = ev.getX();
      mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = ev.getY();

      mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = scaledPointsToScreenPoints(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray);

      ev.setLocation(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0], mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);
      mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

      final int action = ev.getAction();
      switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            // Save the ID of this pointer
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
         }

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            if (mIsScaling && ev.getPointerCount() == 1) {
               // Don't move during a QuickScale.
               mLastTouchX = x;
               mLastTouchY = y;

               break;
            }

            float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

            float[] topLeft = {0f, 0f};
            float[] bottomRight = {getWidth(), getHeight()};
            /*
             * Corners of the view in screen coordinates, so dx/dy should not be allowed to
             * push these beyond the canvas bounds.
             */
            float[] scaledTopLeft = screenPointsToScaledPoints(topLeft);
            float[] scaledBottomRight = screenPointsToScaledPoints(bottomRight);

            dx = Math.min(Math.max(dx, scaledBottomRight[0] - mCanvasWidth), scaledTopLeft[0]);
            dy = Math.min(Math.max(dy, scaledBottomRight[1] - mCanvasHeight), scaledTopLeft[1]);

            mPosX += dx;
            mPosY += dy;

            mTranslateMatrix.preTranslate(dx, dy);
            mTranslateMatrix.invert(mTranslateMatrixInverse);

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            invalidate();
            break;
         }

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
         }

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
         }

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
            final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
               // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
               // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
               final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
               mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
               mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
               mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
         }
      }
      return true;
   }

   private float getMaxScale() {
      return 2f;
   }

   private float getMinScale() {
      return 1f;
   }

   private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
      @Override
      public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
         mIsScaling = true;

         mFocusX = detector.getFocusX();
         mFocusY = detector.getFocusY();

         float[] foci = {mFocusX, mFocusY};
         float[] scaledFoci = screenPointsToScaledPoints(foci);

         mFocusX = scaledFoci[0];
         mFocusY = scaledFoci[1];

         return true;
      }

      @Override
      public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
         mIsScaling = false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
         mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
         mScaleFactor = Math.max(getMinScale(), Math.min(mScaleFactor, getMaxScale()));
         mScaleMatrix.setScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mFocusX, mFocusY);
         mScaleMatrix.invert(mScaleMatrixInverse);
         invalidate();

         return true;
      }
   }

}
```