# Android SDK - Not Scaling at Centre of Touch

Tags: android, sdk, pinchzoom

I have a little problem with my app. I have just implemented pinch zoom, but when I pinch to zoom, the image does not scale at the centre of the 2 points as displayed in the images below. Image 1 is where my fingers are before pinching and image 2 is to display that it has not scaled out at the centre of my fingers like it should.

**Image 1 vs Image 2:**
[image: image1] [image: image2]

Here is my code:

```
        package com.jpiionefourone.guitarimage;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
    import android.view.View;

    public class MultiTouchView extends View {
        private Drawable mIcon;
        private float mPosX;
        private float mPosY;

        private float mLastTouchX;
        private float mLastTouchY;

        private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

        // The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
        private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

        private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
        private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;


        public MultiTouchView(Context context) {
            this(context, null, 0);
        }

        public MultiTouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public MultiTouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.guitar);
            mIcon.setBounds(0, 0, mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), mIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());

            // Create our ScaleGestureDetector
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

            final int action = ev.getAction();
            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
                if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                    mPosX += dx;
                    mPosY += dy;

                    invalidate();
                }

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                        >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
            canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
            mIcon.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }

        private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

                // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
                mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

                invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

Jared

Answer (score 10):

In your `ScaleListener` class you only adjust `mScaleFactor` so, indeed, you image will indeed *not* zoom around the center of you multi-touch gesture!

Additionally, you need to update `mPosX` and `mPosY` to use a different center of scaling.

For one of my own applications, I used something like this:

```
final float scale = detector.getScaleFactor();
mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor * scale, 5.0f));

if (mScaleFactor < 5f) {
   // 1 Grabbing
   final float centerX = detector.getFocusX();
   final float centerY = detector.getFocusY();
   // 2 Calculating difference
   float diffX = centerX - mPosX;
   float diffY = centerY - mPosY;
   // 3 Scaling difference
   diffX = diffX * scale - diffX;
   diffY = diffY * scale - diffY;
   // 4 Updating image origin
   mPosX -= diffX;
   mPosY -= diffY;
}
```

Basically, it calculates the relative change of the origin of your image by

1. grabbing the origin of your multi-touch gesture (`getFocus()`)
2. calculating the difference between your image origin (`diffX` and `diffY`)
3. applying the scale factor
4. and updating the origin of the image by using the scaled difference

This (still) works for my situation. I do not know whether we both use(d) the same coordinate systems, but something like this should help you in properly scaling the image at the center of the multi-touch gesture.

Answer (score 1):

It took me really long to get this working.. however thanks for almost working code! I'm not sure was I just messing around or what but with this changes in code I got my zooming work like I wanted! Hopefully this will safe someones time.

```
mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.5f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 3.0f));
scale = mScaleFactor / scaleAtm


mTranslateMatrix.preTranslate(diffX, diffY);
mTranslateMatrix.invert(mTranslateMatrixInverse);
mPosX += diffX;
mPosY += diffY;
scaleAtm = mScaleFactor;
```

At the beginning scaleAtm = 1.

Comment: Nope, it won't. Because your code is missing. what is scaleAtm ? and where do you use mTranslateMatrix ?

Comment: Hey, im using there little bit different scaling way because I want to be able to drag everything after scaling. You can find the way I'm using here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479859/view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-pan-drag-and-pinch-zoom/12497670#12497670