# Android GPUImage, how to pinch in, out?

Tags: android, image, zooming, gpuimage, pinch

I'm using https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage

In .xml layout file, I use `GPUImageView` to display photo.

Now I want the photo can  drag & zoom in/ out.

Which way I should do:

1. Use a filter like that idea:

> "You can apply a GPUImageTransformFilter to the GPUImagePicture (add
>   the transform filter as a target of the picture, then add the blending
>   filter as a target of the transform filter). You can then apply
>   arbitrary transformations to the image, like scaling, rotation, and
>   translation."

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/51

2. Custom `GPUImageView` like these `ImageViewZoom` libraries:

https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=image+zoom&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

If you have other way, or more detail, please show me.

------------- Update --------------

Because I have some custom views will be added later, so I follow the idea: create ZoomableViewGroup (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19204645/3455160 ) like this:

```
<ZoomableViewGroup
    android:id="@+id/zoom_group"
    android:layout_above="@+id/panel_adjuster"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ZoomableViewGroup>
```

ZoomableViewGroup scales well bet GPUImageView doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Just get your bitmap after applying filter using `getBitmapWithFilterApplied` then set this bitmap to your ImageView and use any library from list of them which you mentioned in option 2.

Comment: In this activity I have both scale & do filter functions. Your way is ok for zooming but  when I do filter, it seems so slow.

Comment: Also about your update - you cannot work with GlSurfaceView like with usual view, you may create your own implementation based on TextureView although.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do pinch zoom using GPUImage. Just capture bitmap from GPUImage using GPUImageView.capture() or GPUImageView.getBitmapWithFilterApplied() and then set this bitmap to imageView for Zoom. You can use ZoomableImageView.java, CustomImageVIew.java or TouchImageView.java etc which is suggested in [Android imageView Zoom-in and Zoom-Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650398/android-imageview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out)
for Pinch zoom.