# Why is the onClickListener for my custom ImageView not registering?

Tags: java, android, imageview, zooming, onclicklistener

I have a panning zooming relative layout within which I add 25 imageviews that represent systems on a starmap. This takes up 2/3 of the screen. The other 1/3 displays information on whichever corresponding system imageview is clicked. However, my onClickListener method is not triggering. I used debug mode with a breakpoint near the start of the onClick method to be sure it wasn't triggering and not just displaying improperly. Here is the relevant code.

```
public class StarMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
InteractiveView starMap;
TextView systemNameView;
TextView systemFactionView;
TextView systemCoordinatesView;
TextView systemPlanetsNumberView;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_star_map);

    starMap = (InteractiveView) findViewById(R.id.myStarMapInteractiveView);
    systemNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.systemNameView);
    systemFactionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.systemFactionView);
    systemCoordinatesView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.systemCoordinatesView);
    systemPlanetsNumberView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.systemPlanetsNumberView);

 for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {          plotSystem(PlayerCharacterInfo.currentPlayerCharacter.occupiedSector.starSystems[i], i);
    }
}
void plotSystem(StarSystem systemToDraw, int systemArrayId){ //draws the white circle images that represent the systems on the map
    StarSystemView viewToDraw = new StarSystemView(this, getResources().getString(systemToDraw.nameId), systemArrayId);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    ShapeDrawable myShape = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());

    myShape.setIntrinsicHeight(10);
    myShape.setIntrinsicWidth(10);
    myShape.getPaint().setColor(-1);

    layoutParams.leftMargin = (systemToDraw.coordinates.x - 50) * 4;
    layoutParams.topMargin = (systemToDraw.coordinates.y - 50) * 4;

    viewToDraw.setImageDrawable(myShape);

    viewToDraw.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewToDraw.setFocusable(true);
    viewToDraw.setClickable(true);

    starMap.addView(viewToDraw, layoutParams);
    viewToDraw.bringToFront();
}
 public void onClick(View view){
StarSystemView clickedView = (StarSystemView) view;
    StarSystem systemToView = PlayerCharacterInfo.currentPlayerCharacter.occupiedSector.starSystems[clickedView.systemArrayId];

    systemNameView.setText(getResources().getString(systemToView.nameId));

    switch(systemToView.systemFactionId){
        case 0:
            systemFactionView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.faction_neutral));
            break;
        case 1:
            systemFactionView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.faction_imperial));
            break;
        case 2:
            systemFactionView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.faction_federation));
            break;
        case 3:
            systemFactionView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.faction_republic));
            break;
    }

    systemCoordinatesView.setText(Integer.toString(systemToView.coordinates.x)+", "+Integer.toString(systemToView.coordinates.y));

    switch(systemToView.numberOfPlanets){
        case 1:
            systemPlanetsNumberView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.basic_one));
            break;
        case 2:
            systemPlanetsNumberView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.basic_two));
            break;
        case 3:
            systemPlanetsNumberView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.basic_three));
            break;
    }
}
```

Also for reference, the interactive view class:

```
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import java.lang.Math;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;



    public class InteractiveView extends RelativeLayout {

    private float mPositionX = 0;
    private float mPositionY = 0;
    float mScale = 1.0f;

    public InteractiveView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
        this.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
    }

    public InteractiveView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
        this.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
    }


    public void setMovingPosition(float lPositionX, float lPositionY){
        mPositionX += lPositionX;
        mPositionY += lPositionY;
    }


    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mScale < 0.5){
            mScale = 0.5f;
        } else if (mScale > 5){
            mScale = 5f;
        }

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        canvas.translate(mPositionX*mScale, mPositionY*mScale);
        canvas.scale(mScale, mScale);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();


    }

    // touch events
    private final int NONE = 0;
    private final int DRAG = 1;
    private final int ZOOM = 2;
    private final int CLICK = 3;

    // pinch to zoom
    private float mOldDist;
    private float mNewDist;
    private float mScaleFactor = 0.01f;

    // position
    private float mPreviousX;
    private float mPreviousY;

    int mode = NONE;

    public OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new  OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            float x = e.getX();
            float y = e.getY();
            switch (e.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // one touch: drag
                    mode = CLICK;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN: // two touches: zoom
                    mOldDist = spacing(e);
                    mode = ZOOM; // zoom
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // no mode
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_UP: // no mode
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // rotation
                    if (e.getPointerCount() > 1 && mode == ZOOM) {
                        mNewDist = spacing(e) - mOldDist;

                        mScale += mNewDist*mScaleFactor;
                        invalidate();

                        mOldDist = spacing(e);

                    } else if (mode == CLICK || mode == DRAG) {
                        float dx = (x - mPreviousX)/mScale;
                        float dy = (y - mPreviousY)/mScale;

                        setMovingPosition(dx, dy);
                        invalidate();
                        mode = DRAG;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            mPreviousX = x;
            mPreviousY = y;
            return true;
        }
    };

    // finds spacing
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }
}
```

Also for reference the imageview class

```
public class StarSystemView extends ImageView {

String systemName;
int systemArrayId;

public StarSystemView(Context context, String systemNameToSet, int arrayIdToSet){
    super(context);
    systemName = systemNameToSet;
    systemArrayId = arrayIdToSet;
}
}
```

I have tried using setOnClickListener(StarMapActivity.this)
I've also tried setting the layout parameters for the StarSystemViews to 12 and 12 instead of wrapping content.
I also put the interactive view to focusable as I read that somewhere.
I've also doublechecked the Android Developer website to see if I can't figure out if I've made any typos or coding errors.

Starting to wonder if imageviews inside a zoomable layout are simply unclickable.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Because of the zoomable imageView, you may need to utilize the onInterceptTouchEvent method.

Comment: The imageview itself is not zoomable. It is a child of a zoomable layout. I do not know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
You are scaling the layout only in the draw of the canvas, not by moving and scaling the actual views in it. Therefore the moment they are scaled, you won't be able to click, as the view is not in the location that it's being drawn at. You will have to do the scaling differently, and you should probably post a new question for advice on how.

Comment: I am assuming you are referring to the OnTouchListener in the InteractiveView. I set it to return false and the pinch-zoom and drag-pan stopped working but the ImageViews still do not trigger the OnClick of the activity.

Comment: So please post more code, where you set the onClick listener and in touch listener.

Comment: The onTouchListener for the InteractiveView code (second block above) is set in it's constructors. The onClickListener for the custom ImageViews is set in the plotSystem method of the StarMapActivity code (first block above) before the view is added to the InteractiveView.

Comment: In response to your update: The plotSystem method takes a StarSystem object as a parameter and each has a different coordinates.x and coordinates.y so they do not get placed in the same location within the layout. (As a note, the starMap does work and scale and pan correctly, with the images dispersed correctly across it.) However, in testing out your point regarding the images not being drawn at their clickable locations, commenting out the canvas scaling and translating code made me realize that this is indeed the problem. How then, to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps I should turn that into a second separate question. Also, I'll be glad to accept #4 as the correct answer.

Comment: I agree, and I have updated my answer. Please reference your new question in the comments, so future users can follow.

Comment: Update: I found a new custom class here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479859/view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-pan-drag-and-pinch-zoom/12497670#12497670 that overrides dispatchTouchEvent to compensate for clicking in regards to the new dragged/zoomed position. However, I had to comment out his overrides of onLayout and onMeasure in order for my views to not be piled on top of one another. It works now, just trying to find how to get it to zoom in and out at the center of the pinch like the InteractiveView does.